# Error warning while using the getSymbols function in R

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to obtain Bitcoin data from yahoo finance using the following code:

```
getSymbols("BTC-USD",from= "2020-01-01",to="2020-12-31",warnings=FALSE,auto.assign = TRUE)
BTC-USD=BTC-USD[,"BTC-USD.Adjusted"]
```

However, I get the following error:

Warning message:

```
BTC-USD contains missing values. Some functions will not work if objects contain missing values in the middle of the series. Consider using na.omit(), na.approx(), na.fill(), etc to remove or replace them.
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fix" in this case? Do you just want to suppress the error message? Do you want to impute missing values? Do you want to add missing values from from other source? Are you sure the missing values are even a problem in your case?

Comment: The missing values message is a warning, not an error.  You can omit the NA's using `na.omit(\`BTC-USD\`)` .

Comment: Hello, I would want to replace them with 0

Answer (score 3):

You've got a first problem which is you're trying to assign to an invalid symbol. Use `_` instead of `-` which is the subtraction operator. If you *really* want the `-`, you can use backticks around the symbol.

Then you can use `is.na` to find the `NA` values and replace them with 0.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("BTC-USD",from= "2020-01-01",to="2020-12-31",warnings=FALSE,auto.assign = TRUE)
BTC_USD <- `BTC-USD`[,"BTC-USD.Adjusted"]
BTC_USD[is.na(BTC_USD)] <- 0

BTC_USD[100:110,]
#           BTC-USD.Adjusted
#2020-04-09         7302.089
#2020-04-10         6865.493
#2020-04-11         6859.083
#2020-04-12         6971.092
#2020-04-13         6845.038
#2020-04-14         6842.428
#2020-04-15         6642.110
#2020-04-16         7116.804
#2020-04-17            0.000
#2020-04-18         7257.665
#2020-04-19         7189.425
```

A better plan is probably to just remove the `NA` rows instead of replacing them with 0:

```
BTC_USD <- BTC_USD[!is.na(BTC_USD),]
```